# Print text (disp, fprintf...) to the command MATLAB window in Labview

Tags: matlab, labview

Is there a way I can print to the Labview MATLAB Command Windows?

disp and fprintf doesn't work.

Sample:

- Create Labview vi
- Add a "MATLAB script"
- Write inside it: `disp('Hello');` or `MyFile;` .m containg this same code.
- Run code

  Nothing is displayed in the "MATLAB Command Window"

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB script window in LabVIEW dont support IDE functions of MATLAB. For example 'disp' is MATLAB own function to display some thing in command window. When calling from LabVIEW, we are not in MATLAB IDE.